# How do I randomize fileroot in lua?

Tags: lua

I have `.lua` file which contains,

```
elseif tid == 39 then
            if     r == 1 then
                sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 1"
            elseif r == 1 or r == 2 or r == 3 or r == 4 or r == 5
                sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 4"
            elseif r == 3 then
                sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 3"
            elseif r == 2 or r == 4 then
                if (ctx.home_team == 1909 or ctx.home_team == 378 or ctx.home_team == 396 or ctx.home_team == 4071) and (ctx.away_team == 1909 or ctx.away_team == 378 or ctx.away_team == 396 or ctx.away_team == 4071) then
                    sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 1"
                else
                    sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 2"
                end
```

This is a game file.
I want to **randomize** those *premier league* folders with `1 ID`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to randomize which folder it assigns to fb, or do you want to randomize the names of the folders?

Comment: The folders actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said, Lua's `math.random(min, max)` is your best bet for randomly generating something. It's worth noting that the min/max values are inclusive, so they are part of the range that it picks from.

If you wanted to randomize the string that you're using for a path, you could do

```
num = math.random(1,4)
path = "PathtoFolder\\Premier League "..num
```

This will put the number on the end of the path, randomly generated from 1 to 4. From there you could assign that path and, assuming that folder with that number exists, it will be a valid path to that folder.

You could also have an array of strings which are the paths to the folders, and then use the `path = pathArray[math.random(1,4]` to randomly select one of them, which you could then use for whatever your code needs to do next.

I'm not quite sure what *exactly* you want to happen.
You said you want to "randomize the folders with 1 ID" or "generate the folders with 1 ID". To me, "randomize the folders" means pick one folder randomly from the bunch of them. I'm not sure what you mean by "with 1 ID".

Can you clear up what you mean by this and perhaps give a more detailed description of what you want the code to do?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.

My answer to your question is,
There is many tid's (Tournament ID) in Lua file.
In my case, I want to use tid=39. That's why I said 1 ID.

And I have 4 folders named as Premier League 1, Premier League 2, Premier League 3, Premier League 4.
Now I want these folders to get selected randomly with tid 39.

I want the code to select those folders randomly.

Once again, thank you for your kind response.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Within the `elseif tid == 39 then` block, try either of the two methods I suggested in the answer, either of them should work if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Is it like - `elseif tid == 39 then
  if r == math.random(1,4) then
   sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 1"..1
  else
   sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 2"..2
  else
   sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 3"..3
  else
   sb = "\\Premier League\\Premier League 4"..4
  end`

Answer (score 1):

Use Lua's math library to select a random number:

```
r = math.random(1, 100)
```

...would choose a random number between 1 and 100, for example, and assign that value to `r`. Apply that function to whatever it is you are trying to randomize. See [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial) for more help.

Comment: Thanks.
I have 4 folders which I want to generate with 1 ID randomly.
Without selecting a specific r = 1 or anything, actually.

Is it possible? or do I have to use  r = math.random(1, 100)?

Comment: `math.random(1, 4)` maybe? If you give an example of exactly what you want to happen, then we can figure out how to make it happen.

Comment: I want those folders to get selected randomly with tid 39.
I want the code to select those folders randomly.

Thank you for responding.